# searching for a string inside products, categories and subcategories

Tags: c#, linq

My data base is made of two Models: Products and Categories.
The Category model itself is made of parent and children categories as for a specific 'ParentID' field relating one to the others.
The relation Parent to Children category is one to many. Children could be any number from zero to 'n'.
The relation Category (or SubCategory) to Products is one to many, the CategoryID being a FK in Products table.

I started writing a search among products' name and description and categories' name:

```
IQueryable<Product> products = 
           from p in db.Products
           where (p.Name.Contains(searchString)
              || p.Description.Contains(searchString)
              || p.Category.Name.Contains(searchString)) 
              select p;
```

As the form allows user to select a specific Category from a DDL,in case a category has been selected I need now to extend my query to its subcategories as follows:

1. looking for the search string into the children categories' name too
2. filtering results to those belonging to Categories and Subcategories only
3. adding new items to previous result

How am I supposed to cycle inside children categories name in order to fulfill points 1.2.3,  **adding** needed result to previously selected ?

Adding models (only relevant fields):

```
 public partial class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int CategoryID { get; set; }
}

 public partial class Category
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int? ParentID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Trying to better explain it. Given:

1. a search string (no search string returns ALL products)
2. a selected Parent Category (optional, no selection returns ALL categories)

I want to retrieve all products where:

CASE 'A': no parent category selected

1. products' name contains the search string
2. all categories contains the search string

CASE 'B': parent category selected

1. products' name contains the search string (only those products
   pertaining to selected parent category AND to its children categories,
   if any)
2. selected parent category name contains the search string
3. selected parent's children categories (if any) name contains the search string

Comment: Could you please add the code defining the relations of `Product` and `Category` to your question? Do you really have a one-to-one relation between `Product` and `Category`? Sounds a bit counter-intuitive for a`Category` to only have one `Product`...

Comment: You are indeed right. I've edited the relation, that's many Products per Category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
IQueryable<Product> products = 
       from p in db.Products
       where (p.Name.Contains(searchString)
          || p.Description.Contains(searchString)
          || p.Category.Name.Contains(searchString)) 
          select p;

if (selectedCategoryID.HasValue) // filter category AND subcategories
        {
            List<int> categories = new List<int>();
            categories.Add(selectedCategoryID.Value);
            foreach(Category child in GetCategories.activeChildrenCategories(db,selectedCategoryID.Value))
            {
                categories.Add(child.ID);
            }

            products = products .Where(p => (categories.Contains(p.Category.ID)));
```

Comment: Working as requested.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your child categories are exposed as an enumerable on the parent category and probably called Categories, then your original query can be extended to search on them by using the `Any()` operator, e.g. `p.Category.Categories.Any(x => x.Name.Contains(searchString))`, so:

```
var products =
    from p in Products
    where (p.Name.Contains(searchString) 
        || p.Description.Contains(searchString) 
        || p.Category.Name.Contains(searchString)
        || p.Category.Categories.Any(x => x.Name.Contains(searchString))
    ) && p.IsDeleted == false && p.IsApproved == true
    select p;
```

Your filter on the parent category can continue to be used as is.

Comment: It's the other way round: as the relation is many Products to one Category, it's the Category model exposing an IEnumerable of Products. Shouldn't it?

Comment: I was taking about the relation of parent Category to child (sub)Categories.

Comment: At the moment there's no relation but parent categories has a parentID null value while children categories has it set to their parent category ID, but I suppose I can write a suitable method for that.

Comment: I mean I do have a suitable method for extracting children given a parent but not a property p.Category.Categories as for your example as there is no "subcategory" field in my db. Could you please explain me what you mean?

Comment: Is this Entity Framework Code First you're using? I would expect Category class to have a `public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }` property, but perhaps you can just do an `Any()` on your method instead.

Comment: EF code first, sure. I still don't understand how your select is supposed to filter only children categories of selected parent that way.